# Call a function based on a global variable is null or not, and if it is null retry the function later

Tags: javascript, reactjs

##### The problem

I have a utility function that will show toast message on the website. `window.globalToast` is a global variable that can be accessed by all react components on my website. Any react components can call below message to show toast message.

The problem is that sometimes `window.globalToast` is not instantiated before those react components, therefore it can be null in this case and the toast message won't show. `window.globalToast`  is being instantiated by a javascript function, which is almost rendered the same time as other react components.

The toasting message:

```js
export const showMessage = (message: string): void => {
  window.globalToast?.addToast(message);
};
```

Other react components just call `showMessage("hello~~")` to show a toast message.

##### My temp fix

My dummy fix is to use `setTimeout` to retry after 1.5 seconds.

```js
export const showMessage = (message: string): void => {
  if (window.globalToast) {
     window.globalToast.addToast(message);
  } else {
    // retry after 1.5 seconds.
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.globalToast.addToast(message);
    }, 1500);
  }
};
```

#### Question

I think one better solution is to check if `window.globalToast` is instantiated or not. If not, above function can retry with a callback(instead of setting 1.5 seconds time lapse)? However, I'm not sure how to change above code to make that happen.

Comment: The usual way you do this is by not using a "window" bound global variable, but instead bundling in the toast library in you react app and importing its message function in components that make use of it. Is there a reason you _need_ the browser-specific window global in this case?

Comment: It would make sense for your setTimeout to call showMessage, so it can check if window.globalToast exists again, and delay another time if not.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to use retry mechanism, but instead of using `setTimeout`, I'd propose you use `setInterval` which will be more reliable.

```
export const showMessage = (message: string): void => {
  if (window.globalToast) {
     window.globalToast.addToast(message);
  } else {
    window.retryCount = 0;
    window.retryInterval = setInterval(function() {
      window.retryCount++;
      if(!window.globalToast) {
         //stop retry after 5 times
         if(window.retryCount >= 5) {
             clearInterval(window.retryInterval)
         }
         return
      }
      window.globalToast.addToast(message)
      //stop interval if it found your function
      clearInterval(window.retryInterval)
    }, 300); //retry every 300 miliseconds
  }
};
```